# Simple Form and Bootstrap 3: Forms don't have bootstrap formatting

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Having an unusual problem with my simple_forms in rails 4 using the bootstrap-sass gem. I generated these form views and noticed the usual bootstrap 3 formatting wasn't being applied to the form.

I read the documentation for simple_form and this should be fixed... Here is an image:
[Image of problem](https://www.flickr.com/photos/127234740@N02/14863490789/lightbox/)

Here's my code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="span4">

        <h2>Sign in</h2>

        <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), html: {class: "form_horizontal"}) do |f| %>


          <%= f.input :email %>


        <br>

          <%= f.input :password %>

        <br>

          <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
          <%= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean, label: false, inline_label: 'Remember me'  %>
          <% end -%>

        <br>

          <div><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></div>
        <% end %>

        <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>


  </div>
</div>
```

Anyone know what might be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there is a problem with ruby gems... when you run bundle install after putting `gem 'simple_form'` into your gem file, it will still install version 3.0.2 instead of the newest version from github (3.1).

What you can do is install this within your gemfile instead: `gem 'simple_form', github: 'plataformatec/simple_form', branch: 'master'`

Then run `bundle install`. It should update your gem to the correct version (3.1.0). Then, run `rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap` again. Every time it stops with a conflict, type 'y' and then  hit enter to overwrite those old initializer files causing the conflict. Terminate the rails server, and then turn it back on. You should be good to go and see the working bootstrap simple-forms if your code is correct.

For example:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@story, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook bootstrap up to simple_form by running this:

```
rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap
```

Comment: Hey bevanp, I ran that command after I installed the simple_form gem today. I just looked back in my console to make sure. I was having this problem before I installed simple_form, though. I had the problem even when I was using the original form_for ... the formatting was not applied. Any ideas why it never worked?

Comment: Is bootstrap working on other forms? Is it working at all on your site?

Comment: It's working everywhere else (even the heading above the form, and the navbar). I noticed that the form fields do highlight with a blue border when they are clicked... But they don't have rounded corners. All of the forms appear this way, and they were generated by devise when I ran rails generate devise:views. I haven't yet created any other forms